# Cron ubuntu не запускает скрипт python

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, cron

Всем доброго времени.
Пытаюсь запустить скрип python в Cron каждые 10 минут.
Если запускать в терминале то все выполняетс, если выполнять через крон то пишет, что нет модуля, он установлен и все выполняется , если в терминале выполнять.
вот ошибка
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'

заранее благодарен.

Comment: Видимо через крон из другого окружения питон запускается.

Comment: Думал об это, сделал по совету-установка пакета от root  пользователя.
всем еще раз спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

либо установите требуемый модуль глобально (из-под `root`) чтобы его мог видеть люой пользователь, либо установите его из-под того пользователя, из-под которого данный скрипт запускает `crontab`. либо используйте `venv`

Comment: Совершенно верно Феоктист Пупырышкин!
перешел под пользователя root установил пакет, все ок

Comment: рад, что помог. думаю, ваш вопрос можно закрывать.

Comment: Да,да...спасибо еще раз.
Где поставить Вам плюсик или отзыв написать.

Comment: У вас как у автора вопроса где-то должен быть функционал "Принять ответ"